# Android TV SDK : Setting Proxy for the Emulator?

Tags: android, android-emulator

I have installed the [Android TV SDK Developer](http://developer.android.com/preview/tv/start/index.html) preview for Windows.  I am in a corporate intranet environment.  I can start the Emulator, but the main screen endlessly loops with the "Preparing Recommendations" animation.  I can navigate to the Settings and see that there is no network (no wired and no ethernet).

I suspect this might be a proxy issue.  I have tried launching the Emulator with the following command:

```
C:\Eclipse_w_Android\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20140624\sdk\tools>emulator -avd AVD_for_Android_TV_1080p_by_Google_X86 -http-proxy http://MY_PROXY_IP:8080
```

(MY_PROXY_IP is replaced with my company's IP address)

It launches the Emulator but doesn't seem to have any effect on the network.

Has anyone else been able to get the Android TV Emulator to fully load in a heavily firewalled / proxied environment?

Answer (score 2):

I thought I was experiencing this issue as well (and had originally commented as such), but I later realized that there was no actually connectivity problem.  Two things to note:

1. "Preparing Recommendations" will appear indefinitely, and I presume this is simply because there are no apps by default feeding recommendations to populate this screen.
2. Both the Ethernet and Wireless items will show that they are not connected.  However, if you run an app that uses the network (a simple WebView is sufficient as long as the app has INTERNET permissions), you'll see that it connects just fine.

I would suggest trying a test app to check connectivity, as there is no other indicator I can find suggesting that it is working properly.  I suspect you'll find that all is well.

Answer (score 0):

you probably forgot the first part username password @ server port

your company probably has the ip setup with  username password